# How Get-AzureRMVM decides which information to include in return?

Tags: azure-powershell

Why some properties for NIC cards for example are returned and some are missing? What governs what is being included in return. Example below showing that for example PrivateIPv4 address is returned but PublicIP is not even though it exists. I understand how to get this information through other means, but I'm wondering why some data is part of return of cmdlet and some is not.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The azure powershell `Get-AzureRmVM` and `Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface` essentially are all calling the REST APIs, what should it return, it is decided by the responses of the REST API which the command calls.

For example, `Get-AzureRmVM` calls  [**Virtual Machines - Get**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get), `Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface` calls **[Network Interfaces - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/networkinterfaces/get)**.